# Add an event to HTML elements with a specific class

Tags: addeventlistener

I'm working on a modal window, and I want to make the function as reusable as possible. Said that, I want to set a few anchor tags with a class equals to "modal", and when a particular anchor tag is clicked, get its Id and pass it to a function that will execute another function based on the Id that was passed.
This is what I have so far:

```
// this gets an array with all the elements that have a class equals to "modal"
var anchorTrigger = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');
```

Then I tried to set the addEventListener for each item in the array by doing this:

```
var anchorTotal = anchorTrigger.length;
for(var i = 0; i < anchorTotal ; i++){
    anchorTrigger.addEventListener('click', fireModal, false);
}
```

and then run the last function "fireModal" that will open the modal, like so:

```
function fireModal(){
    //some more code here ...
}
```

My problem is that in the "for" loop, I get an error saying that anchorTrigger.addEvent ... is not a function.
I can tell that the error might be related to the fact that I'm trying to set up the "addEventListener" to an array as oppose to individual elements, but I don't know what I'm supposed to do.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
anchorTrigger[i].addEventListener...
```